# fields.E304 Reverse accessor clashes in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to migrate these two models:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Person2Person(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

But I have got this error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
website.Person2Person.friend: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Person2Person.friend' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Person2Person.person'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Person2Person.friend' or 'Person2Person.person'.
website.Person2Person.person: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Person2Person.person' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Person2Person.friend'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Person2Person.person' or 'Person2Person.friend'.
```

I want to make a relationship many-to-many in the model `Person`. Why is my code wrong? And how should I fix it?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The code is wrong because `Person` will get a reverse relationship back to `Person2Person.person`, and also to `Person2Person.friend`; the default name would be `Person.person2person_set` but Django can't use the same name for both.

So you could set a `related_name` on either, or both:

```
class Person2Person(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person2persons')
    friend = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='friends')
```

Now `Person.friend`'s related to the `Person2Person` objects that have this `Person` as a friend, and `Person.person2person` to the ones that have this Person as a person.

*However*, why aren't you using a `ManyToManyField` to `'self'` on `Person`?

Comment: Is there a way to disable reversing?

Comment: Yes, related_name='+'

Comment: setting related names solves the problem in django 4